# EXTJS setRootNode possible bug

Tags: javascript, extjs, tree, extjs4.2

I got a treepanel and tree store, and I want to save my treepanel into the store, for that I am using:

```
var treepanel = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
         title: 'Tree example',
         store: store,
         rootVisible: false,
         lines: true
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    root: {
        expanded: true,
    }
});

var button = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
    text: 'test',
    handler: function() {
         treepanel.getRootNode().appendChild({text: 'child',
                                              leaf: true});
         store.setRootNode(treepanel.getRootNode());
    }
});
```

But this doesn't work, however if I create a variable like:

```
var aux = { root:{ 
                  expanded: true,
                  children: [{
                            text: 'child',
                            leaf: true
                           }]
           }}
```

And I use in the same way:

```
store.setRootNode(aux);
```

This works fine. Any idea?, here is fiddle example where you can play with buttons 1 and 2 and check with firebug the error: http://jsfiddle.net/fL5fT/28/

Comment: But when you do `treepanel.getRootNode().appendChild({text: 'child',
                                              leaf: true});` you have already saved that value to the store. Just print on console `store` after that action and you will see that there is child `hola` in your `store`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you did misunderstand some action that you wrote in fiddle:

First of all this code:

```
treepanel.getRootNode().appendChild({text: 'child', leaf: true});
```

already saved item/child to that store. So you dont need to do this:

```
store.setRootNode(treepanel.getRootNode());
```

Next confusion in above line is that you are trying to set new `RootNode` of the `store`. That case will throw error in console because you are trying to set syntactically wrong `RootNode`.

This code will work:

```
var aux = { root:{ 
                  expanded: true,
                  children: [{
                            text: 'child',
                            leaf: true
                           }]
           }}
```

because you have create here correct new `RootNode`.

You need to be aware that making new `RootNode` discards all the previous added items to that store.

Comment: Thanks!, I thought that if I add a node to the treepanel it doesn't update the store since the root node of the store doesn't change, but I found the property 'tree' with the tree update with child nodes added. Thank you!